# Cannot access or delete AWS S3 bucket from console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Learning AWS and mucking about with buckets. I tried to configure a logging bucket for a project, with the following `logging.json` used for the `put-bucket-logging` command in the cli:

```
{
    "LoggingEnabled": {
        "TargetBucket": "logs.bucketname.com",
        "TargetPrefix": "bucketLogs/",
        "TargetGrants": [
            {
                "Grantee": {
                    "Type": "AmazonCustomerByEmail",
                    "EmailAddress": "username@email.com"
                },
                "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
            },
            {
                "Grantee": {
                    "Type": "Group",
                    "URI": "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
                },
                "Permission": "READ"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And after receiving a message in the buckets overview tab in the S3 management console stating "Error: Access Denied", I've been trying to set up a policy that will give me access back so I can just delete the bucket and start over. The policy now looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::logs.bucketname.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure how any of this has caused the root user to be unable to access or delete the bucket in the console. Please advise.

Comment: *"And after observing the error"* ...what was the error you observed?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure how any of this has caused the root user to be unable to access or delete the bucket in the console.

... it's because you set a policy that doesn't grant anyone the right to delete the bucket.  Funnily enough, if you tell AWS to not let anyone delete a bucket, AWS will *not let anyone delete the bucket*.  If you want someone to be able to delete the bucket, you'll need to grant them the `s3:DeleteBucket` policy.